# duplicate last element of matrix

Tags: c, matrix, realloc

In my current C code (see the update), i have a function which receives this two arguments:

```
char** matrix, int max
```

max is the amount of string stored in the matrix. if max is a odd number, i need increment max by 1 AND repeat the last element of the matrix.

I need help in how realloc this matrix to be able to duplicate this last element. acording to the documentation i found, my first thought on solve this problem,`realloc`, accepts the parameters `void *ptr, size_t size`, where the first element is a one-dimensional array?

How I should proceed with this two-dimensional matrix?

**UPDATE**

```
char* function(char** matrix, int max) {
  if(max % 2 != 0) {
    max = max + 1;
    printf("%lu", sizeof(matrix[0]));
    matrix = realloc(matrix, sizeof(matrix[0]));
  }
  if(max == 2) {
    ...
    char* ret = malloc(BLOCK_SIZE);
    strncpy(ret, buf2, BLOCK_SIZE-1);
    return(ret);
  }
  char* submatrix[max/2];

  for(int x=0; x<max; x=x+2) {
    ...
    submatrix[x/2] = buf2;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
  if(max % 2 != 0) {
    max = max + 1;
    char* tmp[max];
    for(int x=0; x<max-1; x++)
      tmp[x] = matrix[x];
    tmp[max-1] = matrix[max-2];
  }
```

Comment: "In my current C code" --> post that code.

Comment: By "amount of string in the matrix" and "repeat the last element of the matrix", do you mean each **row** of the matrix?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog yes

Comment: With your rep you should know how to post a good question.

Comment: @WeatherVane what more is needed here?

Comment: The close votes [suggest this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: In C, `realloc` does not explicitly accept or return an *array* of any dimension. It simply accepts and returns *blocks of memory*. This may be the source of your confusion.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog ok, i tried this: `matrix = realloc(matrix, sizeof(matrix[0]));` but when I test the code with a odd number of elements, the execution crashes with this error: `malloc.c:2882: mremap_chunk: Assertion `((size + offset) & (GLRO (dl_pagesize) - 1)) == 0' failed` (also, I add more code to the question)

Comment: Why not allocate an even number of elements in the first place? Then all you have to do is copy the last data if odd number of elements.

Comment: @WeatherVane because I do not know previously what will be the number of elements I will get.

Comment: Then you must already be using `realloc`, so you could make that an even number of elements.

Comment: I think you are very confused about how C stores multi-dimensional arrays. The array pointed to by `matrix` **does not contain the actual data in the matrix**, but rather *more pointers* to sub-arrays (the *rows* of the matrix) that do.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog so, is there any way to resize a matrix during runtime?

Comment: @KleberMota you must loop though the array `matrix` and do `realloc` on its elements

Comment: @meowgoesthedog but i will not change the size of them. I just want "add" one element (row). think about this matrix as a array of "strings" (char*). I want add one more "string" to this array.

Comment: In that case, you will need to 1) `realloc` on `matrix`, 2) duplicate the array pointed to by the *2nd-to-last* element of `matrix` (previously the last), and 3) assign the new last element of `matrix` to the duplicated array pointer. I assume that you **either** know how large each "string" is, **or** each string is *zero-delimited* (in which case you can use `strlen`)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog last question: based on your suggestions, i get the code in the update 2; now, how I need to know how copy make `matrix` point to the `tmp` pointer. with `matrix = tmp;` i got a segmentation fault error.

Comment: Because you are declaring `tmp` as a static array. Once you return from the function, the values stored in the memory space previously used by `tmp` may change. You must allocate it dynamically: `tmp = malloc(sizeof(char*) * max)`

Comment: @meowgoesthedog now I finally got right. If you want, post the answer now and I will accept it.

Comment: As long as you understand, it's fine. Stackoverflow is about correcting any misunderstandings you have, not helping you debug code. (I fear repercussions for the same reason if I post an answer)

Answer (score 1):

`printf("%lu", sizeof(matrix[0]));`  this will print size of the `char *`

`matrix = realloc(matrix, sizeof(matrix[0]));` will allocate only size of the `char *` bytes - 4 or 8 depending on the system

`sizeof != strlen` and sizeof is not the function - it is evaluated during the complilation.

I would suggest - you should start to learn pointers first (as from your code you do not understand them at all), and then move to something more complicated.